# Round only numeric elements of pandas.DataFrame ignoring string

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':["ab", "cd"],'a':[1.1111,2.2222], 'b':[2.2222,3.3333], 'c':[3.3333,4.4444]})
```

What is a simple way to round only numeric elements with ignoring string elements?

I've read several discussions of SO and try this, but got error.

```
import numpy as np
np.round(df) # => AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute
```

'rint'

I'd like to have the save DataFrame as the following:

```
pd.DataFrame({'x':["ab", "cd"],'a':[1.11,2.22], 'b':[2.22,3.33], 'c':[3.33,4.44]})
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [`df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to select the numeric columns of the DataFrame, use `np.round` to round the numeric sub-DataFrame, and `df.loc` to assign those values to the original DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':["ab", "cd"],'a':[1.1111,2.2222], 'b':[2.2222,3.3333], 
                   'c':[3.3333,4.4444]})

tmp = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
df.loc[:, tmp.columns] = np.round(tmp)
```

yields

```
   a  b  c   x
0  1  2  3  ab
1  2  3  4  cd
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> df[['a', 'b', 'c']] = np.round(df[['a', 'b', 'c']], 2)
>>> df
      a     b     c   x
0  1.11  2.22  3.33  ab
1  2.22  3.33  4.44  cd
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also simply try:

```
df = df.round()
```